# Clarification on Indexes

Tags: sql, oracle12c

To illustrate my question, I will use the following example:

```
CREATE INDEX supplier_idx
  ON supplier (supplier_name);
```

Will the searching on this table only be sped up if the supplier_name column is specified in the SELECT clause? What if we select the supplier_name column as well as other columns in the SELECT clause? Is searching sped up if this column is used in a WHERE clause, even if it is not in the SELECT clause?

Do the same rules apply to the following index as well:

```
CREATE INDEX supplier_idx
  ON supplier (supplier_name, city);
```

Comment: Indexes are usually used to optimize filtering, joins, and aggregations.  You would need to supply particular queries to determine if the index could help those queries (and then it might still depend on the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes can be complex, so a full explanation would take a lot of writing.  There are many resources on the internet.  (Helpful link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT721) to Oracle indexes)

However, I can just answer your questions simply.

```
CREATE INDEX supplier_idx
  ON supplier (supplier_name);
```

This means that any joins (and similar) using the col `supplier_name` and using the col `supplier_name` in a WHERE clause will benefit from an index.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE supplier_name = 'Smith'
```

But simply using the `supplier_name` column in a `SELECT` clause will not benefit from having an index (unless you add complexity to the `SELECT` clause, which I will cover...).  For example - this will **not** benefit from an Index on `supplier_name`

```
SELECT
supplier_name
FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = 1
```

However, if you added some complexity to your SELECT statement, your index could indeed speed it up...For example:

```
SELECT
supplier_name   -- no index benefit
,(SELECT TOP 1 somedata FROM Table2 WHERE supplier_name = Table2.name) AS SomeValue
-- the line above uses the index as supplier_name is used in WHERE
, CASE WHEN supplier_name = 'Best Supplier'
  THEN 'Best'
  ELSE 'Worst'
  END AS FindBestSupplier
--  Also the CASE statement will use the index on supplier_name
FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = 1
```

(The 'complexity' above still basically shows that if the field '`supplier_name`' is used in `CASE`, or `WHERE` aswell as `JOINS` and aggregations, then the INDEX is very beneficial...This example above is a combination of many clauses wrapped into one `SELECT` statement)

But your composite index

```
CREATE INDEX supplier_idx
  ON supplier (supplier_name, city);
```

would be beneficial in specific and important cases (Eg: where the `city` is in the `SELECT` clause and the `supplier_name` is used in the `WHERE` clause), for example

```
SELECT
city
FROM SomeTable WHERE supplier_name = 'Smith'
```

The reason is that `city` is stored alongside the `supplier_name` index values, so when the index finds the `supplier_name` value, it immediately has a copy of the `city` value (stored in the index) and does not need to hit the database files to find any more data.  (If `city` was not in the index, it would have to hit the database to pull the `city` value out, as it does with most data required in the `SELECT` statement usually)

The joins will benefit from an index also, with the example:

```
SELECT
* FROM SomeTable T1
LEFT JOIN AnotherTable T2 
ON T1.supplier_name = T2.supplier_name_2
AND T1.city = T2.city_2
```

So in summary, if you use the field in any comparison expression like a `WHERE` clause or a `JOIN` , or a `GROUP BY` clause (and the aggregations `SUM, MIN, MAX` etc)...then an Index is very beneficial for Tables with over a few thousand rows...
(Usually only makes a big difference when you have at least 10,000 rows in a Table, but this can vary depending on your complexity)

SQL Server (for example) **always** creates any missing indexes that it needs (and then discards them)..So if you do not create the correct indexes manually - the system can slow down as it creates the missing indexes on the fly each time it needs them.  (SQL Server will show you hints on what indexes it thinks you need for a certain query)

Indexes can slow down UPDATES or INSERTS, so they must be used with a little wisdom and balance...(Sometimes indexes are deleted before a batch of `UPDATE`s is performed and then the index re-created again, although this is kinda extreme)

Comment: Could you clarify one of your points: "But simply using the supplier_name column in a SELECT clause will not benefit from having an index (unless you add complexity to the SELECT clause)" What would be an example of adding complexity to the SELECT clause? I apologize if this is a silly question, I am only a beginner.

Comment: @Zampanò No problem...  I will edit my answer and 'beef up' that section to make it more clear ... Please forgive the delay, might take me an hour to get to it

Comment: @Zampanò I have added more to the answer, please forgive my use of T-SQL syntax, but I believe the index theory is roughly the same.  (Although Oracle could actually be more advanced when you get into complex scenarios...) So I caveat the answer with 'In theory' :)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the additions. They are very beneficial in my understanding of indexes. I apologize, but there is one more aspect that I would like clarification on. If we were to use the field from the simple index in an aggregate function such as MAX(supplier_name) without a GROUP BY clause, would we be benefitted by the index like we would be if we had a query such as the following: SELECT supplier_name, MAX(another_column) FROM some_table GROUP BY supplier_name;?

Comment: Hi @Zampanò...in that scenario I don't think the index would be beneficial as finding the supplier_name values to determine the MAX would depend on the results of the WHERE clause ... and if the WHERE clause used any fields other than supplier_name - the results would not be covered by the index so the MAX would still need to 'work hard'...  But with Oracle I could be mistaken.  This is easy enough to test if you have a lot of records...(Clear your cache before each test, I don't know how to do this in Oracle)

Comment: Just to add...despite any THEORY involving indexes - the BEST way to work out what works best is to TEST various combinations...  There is nothing better than empirical testing in your specific scenario.. (ie Create indexes, test..Delete indexes, test again...etc) Just research how 'caching' may affect your testing so you can kill the cache when required